# How to use ANSI escape sequences from an Arduino connected to Putty?

Tags: arduino, putty, ansi-escape

I'm trying to set the background of my Putty terminal to red with ANSI escape sequences from my Arduino.

Arduino sketch code:

```cpp
Serial.begin(9600);
while (!Serial);
// ESC[<color>m
unsigned char graphicsMode[] = {27, '[', 41, 'm'};
Serial.write(graphicsMode, 4);
```

This does not work however. Putty seems to accept the escape sequence (since it doesn't print the characters) but doesn't do anything with it. The screen stays the default color. I can't get it to do anything with cursors either. How do I use escape sequences properly?

Answer (score 2):

I have found the error.

Integer 41 (for the color red) must be split into char '4' and char '1'

```
Serial.begin(9600);
while (!Serial);
// ESC[<color>m
unsigned char graphicsMode[] = {27, '[', '4', '1', 'm'};
Serial.write(graphicsMode, 5);
```